# Where can I customize the appearance of Disqus in my Octopress blog?

Tags: css, blogs, disqus, octopress

I am using Octopress for my blog. I set up Disqus and it shows up on every article. However, I  really need to customize the look because right now there is literally no space between the whole disqus comment box and the right border of the browser window.

I already tried to find the correct SCSS file but I couldn't find it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone searching for a good answer (I am sure @Vassilis works just fine): Just go to

```
octopress/sass/base/_layout.scss
```

In that file go to

```
section.comments {}
```

and add something like this (this align the comments with your blog text)

```
max-width: 500px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are custom styles for disqus anywhere in the default octopress theme.

I would add a new partial undess sass/partials say _disqus.scss and then import the file in _partials.scss

```
@import "partials/disqus";
```